# How to call query-replace-regexp inside a function?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I tend to use query-replace-regexp over an entire buffer rather than at the current position so I regularly use the sequence C-< (beginning-of-buffer),  then C-r (query-replace-repexp).

I'd like to make another function bound to C-S-r (C-R) which does this for me.  I thought that if I simply wrapped it all together such as:

```
(defun query-replace-regexp-whole-buffer ()
  "query-replace-regexp from the beginning of the buffer."
  (interactive)
  (beginning-of-buffer)
  (query-replace-regexp))
```

that this would be adequate, unfortunately though I'm getting some errors.

```
query-replace-regexp-whole-buffer: Wrong number of arguments: #[(regexp to-string &optional delimited start end) "Å Æ
Ç&  " [regexp to-string delimited start end perform-replace t nil] 10 1940879 (let ((common (query-replace-read-args (concat "Query replace" (if current-prefix-arg " word" "") " regexp" (if (and transient-mark-mode mark-active) " in region" "")) t))) (list (nth 0 common) (nth 1 common) (nth 2 common) (if (and transient-mark-mode mark-active) (region-beginning)) (if (and transient-mark-mode mark-active) (region-end))))], 0
```

I can't really see what I'm doing wrong,  hopefully someone can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When called from Lisp, `query-replace-regexp` expects to be passed regular expression and the intended replacement as arguments. If you want to emulate the questions asked when invoked interactively, you need to use `call-interactively`:

```
(defun query-replace-regexp-whole-buffer ()
  "query-replace-regexp from the beginning of the buffer."
  (interactive)
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (call-interactively 'query-replace-regexp))
```

Also note that one should never call `beginning-of-buffer` from Lisp code; it will do unnecessary work, such as pushing the mark and printing a message.

Comment: Thanks for your help and also thats a good tip about not using `beginning-of-buffer` :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to read arguments yourself and pass them to `query-replace-regexp`... This could be done by extending your interactive, so function will look something like:

```
(defun query-replace-regexp-whole-buffer (regex to-string)
  "query-replace-regexp from the beginning of the buffer."
  (interactive "sRegex to search: \nsString to replace: ")
  (save-excursion
     (goto-char (point-min))
     (query-replace-regexp regex to-string)))
```

Comment: just noticed another answer - this could be better for you, as you don't need to explicitly read arguments

Comment: Thanks for your help, this is also interesting to know how the interactive statement works.  I may have to look at elisp in a bit more detail.

Comment: `save-excursion` is a good idea, and so is showing the use of `interactive`. One downside compared to my answer is that you don't get the fancy prompting that `query-replace-regexp` performs interactively. (For the OP: use `M-x find-function RET query-replace-regexp RET` to navigate to the source of `query-replace-regexp`, and don't forget to install the elisp sources package if you haven't already.)

Comment: yes, I thought about pointing to original source, but decided that it could be too complicated for author of question :-)

Comment: This is actually very useful to me since a lot of my regexp replaces are the same.  Emacs is so helpful.